# Entity Framework update database

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

Using Entity Framework 6 (with code first approach), there is a exception if the database is not up to date

> System.InvalidOperationException: "The model backing the 'xxx' context has changed since the database was created.

Is there a way to check, if the database is up to date and if not, update the database to the latest version from within the application itself?

Comment: You need to look at database migrations in EF.  Each time you make changes to the model, you should generate a migration and run that against the database.

Comment: all migrations are there. I want to update an existing database with these migrations from the application itself and not from the packet manager console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works using the DBMigrator Class

```
Dim migrator = New DbMigrator(new migrations.Configuration())
migrator.Update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your Database up to date with the EF Model is paramount.

For every change you make to the model of your context, there must be a migration to the database.

To maintain the integrity of the relationship between model and db you must:

1. `Add-Migration migrationName_versionx.x.x`
2. `Update-Database`

The exception you have experienced `System.InvalidOperationException:` is telling you that you that your model has not been migrated into your database. This means that EF is not able to work properly with possible queries you mave have.

Your database will keep a migration history which you can use to validate the integrity. If you are in doubt, simply apply a new migration and see if there were any changes.

Comment: Sure, all migrations are in the project. but assuming I've shipped version one to a customer and doing version 2 now which contains database changes. The changes has to be implemented at the customer also. And because all migrations are in the project I thought there should be a way to update an existing database from within the application itself and not from the paket manager console?